# c# regex to get a text onto the same line

Tags: c#, regex, string

I know this could be done with a bunch of for loops but there has to be a nice regex way....

I have a text file, with lines beginning with category string followed by a ':' and some more text eg

```
name:john
job:engineer
description:engineering is blah blah blah
blah blah bla
name: sally
job:police woman
description:catches theives
name:.....
```

How do i get all category descriptions onto the same line?

```
name:john
job:engineer
description:engineering is blah blah blah blah blah bla
name: sally
job:police woman
description:catches theives
name:.....
```

given that i have an array of the categorieds 'name,job, description'

here is my code, that does it through loops and checks, its slower than regex i imagine.

```
private static string congatenateMultiLineHeaderStrings(string output, string[] headersArray)
{
    string[] outputLinesArray = output.Split('\n');
    string outputOneLinePerHeader = "";
    for (int lineNo = 0; lineNo < outputLinesArray.Length; lineNo++) //for each line
    {
        bool hasHeader = false;
        for (int headerNo = 0; headerNo < headersArray.Length; headerNo++) //for each header....
        {
            if (outputLinesArray[lineNo].Contains(headersArray[headerNo])) //if the line contains a header...
            {
                hasHeader = true;
            }
        }
        if (!hasHeader)
        {
            outputOneLinePerHeader += " "+outputLinesArray[lineNo]; //outputLinesArray[lineNo];//attach this line to prev
        }
        else
            outputOneLinePerHeader += "\n" + outputLinesArray[lineNo];
    }
    return outputOneLinePerHeader;
}
```

Comment: i started using for loops which im sure i can succeed at but that is cumbersome and slow. I have no idea how to do it with regex which if possible would be faster.

Comment: Can you tell us what is the expected output you require ? Try to be clear so that we can get back with the solution soon.

Comment: don't worry about that... post your looping code, otherwise you might get downvotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the loopy loop way, its cpu intensive though

```
private static string congatenateMultiLineHeaderStrings(string output, string[] headersArray)
{
    string[] outputLinesArray = output.Split('\n');
    string outputOneLinePerHeader = "";
    for (int lineNo = 0; lineNo < outputLinesArray.Length; lineNo++) //for each line
    {
        bool hasHeader = false;
        for (int headerNo = 0; headerNo < headersArray.Length; headerNo++) //for each header....
        {
            if (outputLinesArray[lineNo].Contains(headersArray[headerNo])) //if the line contains a header...
            {
                hasHeader = true;
            }
        }
        if (!hasHeader)
        {
            outputOneLinePerHeader += " "+outputLinesArray[lineNo]; //outputLinesArray[lineNo];//attach this line to prev
        }
        else
            outputOneLinePerHeader += "\n" + outputLinesArray[lineNo];
    }
    return outputOneLinePerHeader;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok let us *distill* this down to the real problem.

The problem is that a line of text can *optionally* span two lines and that a parser which reads it can fail when it comes to the multi-line scenario. Hence at its root, a two line value. What if we could simply remove the CRLF (Carriage Return Line Feed), `\r\n` when it encounters the above scenario?

The tools at our disposal are Regex, but we want to replace a `\r\n` with a  (space) and not just match the text. So by using a variant of regex, `regex.replace` and giving that method a pattern to match the `\r\n` and replace it with a space  we can achieve our goal.

So let us define the data we are looking at, both single line descriptions and double line descriptions and we will give a visual hint as to a second line by modifiying the OPs data

```
string data = @"name:john
job:engineer
description:engineering is 1blah 1blah 1blah
2blah 2blah 2blah
name: sally
job:police woman
description:catches theives
name:OmegaMan
job:Computer Programmer
description:Answers questions
on StackOverflow";
```

But...we don't want to replace it *if* the next line does have a `:` character signifying a new key value pair, so that needs to be in the pattern somehow to skip those lines.

The following regex replace looks for a `\r\n` and through the use of regex `lookaheads` (a lookahead is simply meta operations (*hints*) that the regex parser does while text processing before committing to a match). By providing hint logic we can direct an *actual* match to match or not by the hints.

I have added a third set of data by the name of OmegaMan whose description spans two lines, while the police doesn't, to verify it works. Here is the documented code:

```
    string pattern =@"
    (\r\n)      # Find a CRLF and 'match' it (first match $1) to be replaced if....
    (?!         # Stop the match if it *meta* matches next logic 
       (?=.+:)  # Is there a : on the next line?          
     )          # If the look ahead is true the match is stopped and the \r\n is skipped (no match)
    (.)         # But if not we then need to match  at least one character; 
                # and don't replace it. This is the second match as $2."

    // Ignore Pattern Whitespace only allows us to comment the pattern; 
    // it does not affect text processing.
    Console.WriteLine (Regex.Replace(data, 
                                     pattern, 
                                     " $2",    // Replace \r\n with a space and the one matched character.
                                     RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace));
```

The result of the console writeline is

```
name:john
job:engineer 
description:engineering is 1blah 1blah 1blah 2blah 2blah 2blah
name: sally
job:police woman
description:catches theives
name:OmegaMan
job:Computer Programmer
description:Answers questions on StackOverflow
```

Comment: wow, nearly, 'we don't want to replace it if the next line does have a : character signifying a new key value pair,' is incorrect though. we want to replace it if the next line does not have a 'header' found in the headersarray. Should we loop through the header array first, f no match then do varient of the above?

Comment: @Fearghal What is in the `headersarray`? The above regex solution takes any `category` line where the next line does not have a `category` with `:` in it and combines it into one line. You specifically asked "How do i get all category descriptions onto the same line?". Where is the headers array? What is a header?

Comment: The headerArray is the list of possible headers so its actually easier issue than you think - i cant assume : will only appear in after the header/category string, it may appear in a dateTime string. But i do have the headerArray which tells me all the possible starting strings.

Comment: @Fearghal I fully understand what you are saying. But by this headers list, this make this question an whole different animal. Regex is a pattern match operation and if one doesn't have the patterns to match against; regex falls short. I would have answered your question differently if you would have stated that the `headerarray` is a component key to the answer you seek. When I read your post, headerarray was simply something you had in code which was not apparent if it applied or not. 

The regex I provided will take any two lines and make them one, which regardless of category will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this supposing `str` is the text.

```
str = Regex.Replace("\n", "$flag$").Replace(str, @"\$flag\$(?=\w+:)", "\n")
.Replace("$flag$", "");
```

Comment: where do i insert my array element which i have to check against - this will simply congatenate everything onto one line no?

Answer (score 0):

In this example we are resolving the problem of parsing across lines by putting all the data into a giant blob of text... we are then running a search and replace on the giant blob to make sure that each line ends right before the word name:

finally we use a regular expression to get the data out...

```
  List<string> stringList = new List<string>(){
                                        "name:john",
                                        "job:engineer",
                                        "description:engineering is blah blah blah blah blah bla",
                                        "blah blah blah blah blah bla",
                                        "drives a skooter",

                                        "name:Ted", 
                                        "job:engineer",
                                        "description:engineering is blah blah blah blah blah bla",
                                        "blah blah blah blah blah bla",
                                        "has a mustang",

                                        "name:Jim Bob", 
                                        "job:engineer",
                                        "description:engineering is blah blah blah blah blah bla",
                                        "blah blah blah blah blah bla",
                                        "drives a corvette"
                                        };


        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var mystring in stringList)
        {
            sb.Append(string.Format("{0} ", mystring));
        }


        sb.Replace("name:", "\nname:");

        string pattern = "(?=name)\\s*(?<name>.+)(?=job:)\\s*(?<job>.+)(?=description:)\\s*(?<description>.+)";

        foreach( Match m in Regex.Matches(sb.ToString(),pattern,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        {
            string name = m.Groups["name"].Value.Trim();
            string job = m.Groups["job"].Value.Trim();
            string description = m.Groups["description"].Value.Trim();

        }
```

Comment: you array has the lines already sorted, should it not have all the lines as the originally are and then sort them?

Comment: Could you please share the format of the string output you are looking for? Are you looking for a line with engineer,police woman

Comment: the result i am looking for is in question. I have an array of the categories, each line should start with these category strings eg 'description:' but some lines are a continuation of th eprevious line eg 'blah blah blah' i want to attach the 'blah b;ah blah line to the 'description:' line

Comment: I think I understand the issue, and I believe I have solved it with my new answer

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex.Replace(allContent, @"(?m)(?<=^description:.*$)\n", " ");
```

Comment: this doesnt attach the line 'blah blah blah' to the end of the line 'description:engineering blah blah blah' does it?

Comment: how do i use my string array of categories with this?

Answer (score 0):

use this pattern

```
(\r?\n)(?!\w+:)
```

and replace with a white space like in this [demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/21)

Comment: where do i use this? do i loop through the text line by line looking for lines that dont have a category word eg 'description:'?